# Rxjs callback on every success/error call

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a scenario like this,

```
this.uiDataObservable.pipe(
    tap(() => this.showLoader.next(true)),
    map((uiData) => this.createHttpRequest(uiData),
    switchMap((httpRequest) => this.apiService.get(httpRequest),
    map((response) => this.createUISucessData(response),
    )
).subscribe(
    (success) => /* show data on UI */, 
    (error) => /* show error on UI */, 
    );
```

Now in this example what is the right place to call `this.showLoader.next(false)`.

- I cannot use `finalize` because my stream never ends.
- I cannot use the third callback `complete` of `subscribe` block as it never
  gets calls on error.

What is the correct `rxjs` way of handling this situation?

Comment: Add that line to both the success and error callbacks when you subscribe. As an aside, multiple lambdas as arguments to subscribe are being depreciated. It may make sense to switch to passing in an observer object -> `{next: v => /* */, error: e => /* */}`

Comment: Adding it to success and error callback is something not I am looking for here. I am expecting something more rxjs way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found better alternative, code goes like this:

```
this.uiDataObservable.pipe(
    tap(() => this.showLoader.next(true)),
    map((uiData) => this.createHttpRequest(uiData),
    switchMap((httpRequest) => {
        return this.apiService.get(httpRequest).pipe(
             catchError((error) => {
                 /* show error on UI */
                 return of({ /* return empty response or undefined */ })
             })
        )
    },
    map((response) => this.createUISucessData(response),
    )
).subscribe(
    (data) => { 
        this.showLoader.next(false);
        /* show data on UI */,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Adding it to success and error callback is something not I am looking for here. I am expecting something more rxjs way. - OP

I'm not sure why using RxJS callbacks should be considered less RxJS than anything else. Regardless, in an effort to not repeat `this.showLoader.next(false)`, you could create a custom operator that handles the calls for you.

That might look as follows:

```ts
function tapNxtErr<T>(fn: () => void): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return tap({
    next: _ => fn(),
    error: _ => fn()
  });
}

this.uiDataObservable.pipe(
  tap(() => this.showLoader.next(true)),
  map(uiData => this.createHttpRequest(uiData)),
  switchMap(httpRequest => this.apiService.get(httpRequest)),
  map(response => this.createUISucessData(response))
  tapNxtErr(() => this.showLoader.next(false))
).subscribe({
  next: success => /* show data on UI */, 
  error: error => /* show error on UI */
});
```